# TF200016: The following project does not exist: ProjectFirstPartOfTheName. Verify that the name of the project is correct and that the project exists

Tags: azure-devops, tfs

I configuring repository permissions by usin **tf git permission** tool in this way:

```
tf git permission /deny:CreateBranch /group:"[%1]\Contributors" /collection:https://dev.azure.com/<CompanyName>/ /teamproject:"%2" /repository:%3
```

It works fine but when the project has spaces in the name it fails with the error of the subject. I attempted with (for the first parameter, %1):

- "Project Name"
- Project%20Name and "Project%20Name" as it appears in the browser's address bar.

No matter what I do the error is the same, it only recognizes the first part before the blank:

*"TF200016: The following project does not exist: **Project**. Verify that the name of the project is correct and that the project exists on the specified Azure DevOps Server."*

I do not use spaces in the names of new projects but this one already existed and I would like to keep as the teams know it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @torek, although this topic is about Team Foundation Version Control Tool, the issue itself is related to Azure DevOps. That is the reason because I did not add the "tfs" tag but the "git" one, because the command line is "tf git permission ..."

Comment: The thing is, Git doesn't have permissions in the first place - that's always some kind of add-on. If it's Azure, that does call for some azure tag(s), though.

Answer (score 0):

I found a soluction some time ago, after deciding not to use long names in projects and Solution is to use the "dequotator" character (~) in the CMD parameter declaration. That is, declare CMD parameters like "%~1" instead of "%1".

PS ..._tools\devOps> .\create-branch-permission-deny.cmd "MLOps Demo" "MLOps Demo" "MLOps Demo"

Without removing quotes (using "%i" in batch file)

```
....\repos\_tools\devOps>tf git permission /deny:CreateBranch /group:"["MLOps Demo"]\Contributors" /collection:https://dev.azure.com/<companyName>/ /teamproject:""MLOps Demo"" /repository:"MLOps Demo"
TF200016: The following project does not exist: MLOps. Verify that the name of the project is correct and that the project exists on the specified Azure DevOps Server.
```

After removing quotes (using "%i" in batch file)

```
....\_tools\devOps> .\create-branch-permission-deny~.cmd "MLOps Demo" "MLOps Demo" "MLOps Demo"

....\_tools\devOps>tf git permission /deny:CreateBranch /group:"[MLOps Demo]\Contributors" /collection:https://dev.azure.com/<companyName>/ /teamproject:"MLOps Demo" /repository:"MLOps Demo"
=======================================================================================================================
Project: MLOps Demo
Repository: MLOps Demo
(Inherit: Yes)

  ...
  ...
  Identity: [MLOps Demo]\Contributors
    Allow:
    Deny:              CreateBranch
    Allow (Inherited): GenericRead, GenericContribute, CreateBranch, CreateTag, ManageNote, PullRequestContribute
    Deny (Inherited):
```